# The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/moonlight-team/pinta/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, repository

Any time I try to install anything or run apt update, I get this error:

> E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/moonlight-team/pinta/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: Did you check the 3rd party PPA supported bionic (18.04).  It supports karmic, lucid, & maverick which are 2009-2010 releases.  *Meaning it won't work in your release, plus being so long ago, I'd not want to use it on my system as I value security too highly*

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate of a generic answer. I reopened it to add some specific help but the original close link was: https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-i-added-does-not-have-a-release-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking deeper, going through `./pool/main/p/pinta/` you can see this repos is *ancient*:

```
pinta_0.5+dfsg-1~dhx1_all.deb   2010-11-03 20:27
```

While I'm sure you can download the packages manually, I would suggest this is a dead repo and should be left well alone. The "official" `pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable` repo is in a similar state, last updated in 2015.

Pinta itself seems a bit abandoned (last release was 2015) and while it still works (I have it installed) the packaging for it, how it links into the rest of the system, needs regular maintenance as Ubuntu changes. Your best bet is probably installing it from [a Flatpak package](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.PintaProject.Pinta). These have the advantage that they get bundled with most of their requirements so should keep working indefinitely, often to a fault.