# Missing Release file when running SUDO APT UPDATE in 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates

I just ran sudo apt update, as the first step in upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04. This was part of the response:

```
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [275 kB]

Err:11 https://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu focal-getdeb Release 404  Not Found [IP: 206.189.192.106 443]

Get:18 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,046 kB]
```

... I've skipped a few lines here...

```
Get:33 http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [880 B]                                                
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                   
E: The repository 'http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu focal-getdeb Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

OK. So why is the update trying to use https when the path in my Software & Update settings is http://archive.getdeb.net...?

Cheers

JM

Comment: There are 2764 results for does not have a release file. Here is one for you that has an answer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143963/the-repository-http-ppa-launchpad-net-moonlight-team-pinta-ubuntu-bionic-rele

Comment: Thank you David. I don't know how you narrowed it down,  but even the one with an answer has a lot of branches and potential options. In particular, the comment "To summarize, you need to remove the added PPA, and use another one that has packages for your particular release." appears helpful:  but I don't know if there is an suitable alternative PPA (or how I would choose it), or whether it would be safe to just deselect the existing one.